# Selenium IDE login twice

Tags: selenium, if-statement, logging, ide

I have to input credentials and log in into page twice by using Selenium IDE. How can I do it by using if-else statement? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can. But your question is quite vague. Maybe you could post your code? [Learn about control flow (if-else, forEach, etc.) here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/control-flow).

Another possible solution could be to use the recording feature of Selenium IDE. [This article shows you how to create a login test](https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-ide-login-test).